# How to know the path of current binary file?

Tags: c, linux, file, path, directory

I am creating a file inside a c file:

```
open("my.txt"...);
```

Compile this program as /user/abc/linux/c/program01. Then if I am in directory /user/abc and try to type

```
'linux/c/program01'
```

I found that the file name "my.txt" is created under current directory of /user/abc/my.txt. But I wish to file is created under the directory where the binary program01 is put.

So my question is: how does a program know which directory itself is sitting in?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: getcwd - google it. Don't post post without the prior search

Comment: @alinsoar He doesn't need the current directory but the directory where the binary is located. Please read the question carefuly.

Comment: Thanks Ajay, my question is really different!